# Ошибка с проверкой подписки на TeleBot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Код:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_command(message):
    channel_member = bot.get_chat_member(chat_id='-1001974463696', user_id=message.from_user.id)
    if channel_member.status == 'member' or channel_member.status == 'creator':
        bot.reply_to(message, 'Ты в главном меню')
    else:
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        channel1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Подписаться', url='ссылка')
        check_sub = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Проверить подписку', callback_data='check_subscribe')
        markup.add(channel1, check_sub)
        bot.reply_to(message, 'Подпишись!\n'
                              'После подписки на все каналы, нажмите кнопку проверки подписки.',
                     reply_markup=markup)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback(call):
    if call.data == 'check_subscribe':
        bot.delete_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.id)
        start_command(message=call.message)
```

После нажатия 'Проверить подписку' выдает ошибку, в чем может быть ошибка?

Ошибки:

```
    *2023-07-16 12:19:49,936 (__init__.py:1083 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "Threaded polling exception: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: replied message not found"
2023-07-16 12:19:49,937 (__init__.py:1085 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "Exception traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Новая папка\Python\Lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1074, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Новая папка\Python\Lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 147, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Новая папка\Python\Lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 90, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Новая папка\Python\Lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 6770, in _run_middlewares_and_handler
    result = handler['function'](message)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\KIRI\Python\bot_rassilka\main.py", line 29, in callback
    start_command(message=call.message)
  File "E:\KIRI\Python\bot_rassilka\main.py", line 21, in start_command
    bot.reply_to(message, 'Подпишись!\n'
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Новая папка\Python\Lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 4515, in reply_to
    return self.send_message(message.chat.id, text, reply_to_message_id=message.message_id, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Новая папка\Python\Lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1549, in send_message
    apihelper.send_message(
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Новая папка\Python\Lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 264, in send_message
    return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload, method='post')
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Новая папка\Python\Lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 162, in _make_request
    json_result = _check_result(method_name, result)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Новая папка\Python\Lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 189, in _check_result
    raise ApiTelegramException(method_name, result, result_json)
telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: replied message not found*
```

Comment: Какую ошибку? (Устал уже постоянно такие комментарии писать...)

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/zCVrUNv

Comment: Приведите это в виде текста **в вопросе**, нажмите кнопку [edit].

Comment: сделал. это все ошибки

Comment: Попробуйте заменить `start_command(message=call)` на `start_command(message=call.message)`.